# How to use res.send() return Set or Map Object

Tags: node.js, express, set

express@4.15.3

```
router.get('/set-object', async (req, res) => {
    let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
    let b = new Map();
    b.set('hello', 'world')
    res.send({a: a, b: b});
})
```

but I get result:

```
{
    "a": {},
    "b": {}
}
```

why res.send() or res.json() Set or Map is `{}`

Comment: I know ```res.send({a: [...a], b: [...b]});```, but it is not what I ask

Answer (score 3):

`res` is sending JSON, but `Set` and `Map` are structures (types) that store data, so you need to convert them to JSON-compatible types before sending as a response. Use `Array.from` function or `spread` operator like this:

```
res.send({a: Array.from(a), b: Array.from(b)}); // You might need a more complex logic for mapping b
// OR
res.send({a: [...a], b: [...b]});
```

Comment: JSON supports ```Number String Boolean Array  Object``` , I print ```console.log(typeof a)``` is object, why it need to convert to JSON-compatible.

Comment: That's right. So you need to convert your data to one of these types before sending it as a response body.

Comment: The type is ``Object`` because everything in javascript is ``Object`` - all types are derived from ``Object`` . But to access ``Set`` values you need to iterate over it's keys and values. ``JSON`` works with plain ``Objects``, not the derived types.

Comment: Refer to JSON stringify [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to see the examples of usage.

Answer (score 2):

you need to destruct them into an array

```js
router.get('/set-object', async (req, res) => {
    let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
    let b = new Map();
    b.set('hello', 'world')
    res.send({a: [...a], b: [...b]});
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve that using `Object.fromEntries()` function for Maps and destructuring (as others suggested) for Sets. Please note that `Object.fromEntries()` function has no support on Internet Explorer yet based on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
const b = new Map();
b.set(1, 'one');
b.set(2, 'two');
b.set('hello', 'world');

console.log({
  a: [...a],
  b: Object.fromEntries(b)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if we have map named as filesMap and we need to send this map in response
then we can send the response, in this way, hope this answers the above question or 
any question in general where you are required to send map in response.

```
return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify([...filesMap]));
```