# How to retrieve a JSON response from the client side in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I'd like to know how can I successfully retrieve a JSON response in NodeJS from the client side.
My goal is to get the list of instances of a Google Compute Engine project.

EDIT: The following code has been produced after following Murtaza's suggestions on the comment section. I haven't managed to make it successful. I've also included the function "listVM", where I call the API method to get the list of instances.

Server code

```
// Listar las máquinas virtuales 
app.get('/vms_client/list', (req,res) => {

  listVM().then(instances => {
    //console.log(instances) -> shows: Map(1) { 'instName' => 'instId' }  ;
    res.status(200).json(instances); 
    console.log("Listado de máquinas devuelto")
  }
  ).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json({ error: e })
  })

})

async function listVM(){
  let instances = new Map();

  const response = await compute.instances.list({
    project: projectIdParam,
    zone: zoneParam,
  });

  response.data.items.forEach(instance =>
  {
      instances.set(instance.name, instance.id)
  });

  return instances;

}
```

Client code

```
async function getInstances() {
    let instances = new Map();
    try {
        const response = await fetch(APILINK + "list", { method: 'GET' });
        console.log(response);
        const data = await response.json(); // tenemos que hacer "await" ya que "response.json()" devuelve una Promise
        instances = data; 
        console.log(instances);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${error.message}`);
    }
    return instances;    
}
```

In the server, in "console.log(instances)", before "res.status(200).json(instances)", the "instances" object is shown as a Map with the instance id and instance name of the existent instance.
I don't understand why the client gets an undefined JSON object.

I imported express and cors in the server.

Hopefully someone can give some clue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution.
The problem was on the format I was sending the JSON from the server.

I had to convert the map into an object before sending it, by using the function `Object.fromEntries`.

Here's the current server code:

```
app.get('/vms_client/list', (req, res) => {
  listVM().then(instancesMap => {
    const instancesObj = Object.fromEntries(instancesMap);
    res.status(200).json(instancesObj); 
    console.log("Listado de máquinas devuelto")
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json({ error: e })
  })
})
```

I followed the instructions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68333092/13880991

Thank you Murtaza for your help, after 3 weeks I finally have overcome this problem, it was so easy but it took me so much to find out the cause :).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use instance before the API response is received. You need to use async await approach for the same.

Server code

```js
// Listar las máquinas virtuales a las que tiene acceso un usuario cuyo ID es "userId"
app.get('/vms_client/list', (req,res) => {

  listVM().then(instances => {
    //console.log(instances) -> shows: Map(1) { 'instName' => 'instId' }  ;
    console.log("Listado de máquinas devuelto")
    res.status(200).json(Object.fromEntries(instances.entries())); 
  }
  ).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json({ error: e })
  })

})
```

Client code will be same

Comment: Hi Murtaza, I understand, I supposed I didn't have to call await in the client as it was already done in the server. I applied your code but I'm still getting a response with an empty body.

Comment: @Marctrix I just added the server code. You can try this.

Comment: Hi Murtaza, I'm still getting an empty response from the client side. I don't understand why you do "instances = await fetch(APILINK + userId + "/list", { method: 'GET' })" in the client code, shouldn't it be instances equal to the JSON data returned by the fetch, like I've on my code.

Comment: Hi @Marctrix, I did some research on this. We cannot return map in the API. We have to convert the map to object before returning. You will have to replace the line res.status(200).json(data); with res.status(200).json(Object.fromEntries(data.entries())); and it should work fine. Client code will be same.

Comment: Hi Murtaza, it's been 2 months since your message. I was checking my notifications and found out your message now. I managed to got it working by doing "res.status(200).json(Object.fromEntries(map))", I didn't need to do "map.entries()".